# Is there a way to clone a tab in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have a predefined Tab with some Nodes inside and I want the user to be able to duplicate that tab when clicking on a certain button.

The tabs are contained in a TabPane (`tabPane`)

I tried with :

```
tabPane.getTabs().add(tabPane.getTabs().get(0));
System.out.println(tabPane.getTabs().size());
```

The print line shows that the tabPane size is indeed increasing but nothing is displayed in the UI, no tabs are added to the tabPane.

So, is there a way to duplicate a tab, or I am doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: In JavaFX component/Nodes may only have one parent. So the best way to 'clone' the tab is by creating a replica and add that one instead. (I am not sure if content need to be 'linked' as well, as that may provide a challenge).

Comment: @n247s, When I add a ```new Tab()``` to tabPane it works, an empty fresh tab is added. but adding an already existing tab seems not to work.

Comment: As noted, you can't have the same `Tab` duplicated in the same `TabPane` or be in different `TabPane`s simultaneously—you have to create a _new_ `Tab`. If you have a properly designed model then doing this should be relatively easy. Write a method that creates the `Tab` and just call that method again with the same model. If you want to "clone" the tab but keep the models separated afterwards, then add a way to "clone" your model.

Comment: Use a Controller for the Tab Content. Create a method that clones the Controller and creates an exact replicate.  Add a new Tab with the content of the cloned Controller :thinking: